# How can I change history by directly editing patches and metadata?

Tags: git, rebase

Git has a bunch of procedures for altering history.
(`rebase`, `filter-branch`, `commit --ammend`, `guilt`, `stacked git`, etc)

However, it may sometimes be preferable if there was a procedure to turn the last few commits into a file containing a series of patches with the commit metadata, which could be freely edited, and then turned back into a rebased history (assuming the patches still applied).

Does anyone have a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [magit](https://github.com/magit/magit) which solves roughly this problem very well for me.

Answer (score 1):

During your `git rebase -i`, set the commits you want to change to be `edit`ed. Then you can modify them and re-commit with another message all you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [`git format-patch`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html)  and [`git am`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-am.html), but that would generate one file per commit though.
You can also use `git diff`, but that would combine several commits into one patch.

Comment: @Ramkumar: good idea, I never tried it and would be interested to see if it works.